# Specify date from a character with lubridate (mdy) in r

Tags: r, lubridate

I have problems using the mdy formatting of the `parse_date_time` function of `lubridate`.

```
# does work
date <- "21 December 2016"
date_text <- parse_date_time(date, "dmy", tz = "UTC")
# does work
date <- "2016 December 21"
date_text <- parse_date_time(date, "ymd", tz = "UTC")
# does work
date <- "2016 21 December"
date_text <- parse_date_time(date, "ydm", tz = "UTC")
# DOES NOT WORK
date <- "December 21 2016"
date_text <- parse_date_time(date, "mdy", tz = "UTC")
```

Can anyone tell me why the last version won't work and what to do to make it work?
I get the message:

```
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue. All of them work fine with me. Restart your R session and just try the last one.

Comment: Did so, still does not work. Unfortunately cannot test it on another machine right now.

Comment: All works fine for me as well